# Include repo that is intermittently available: install.packages timeout

Tags: r

For my company, we have a repository for internally created packages at an internally hosted location. It is accessible while we are on our network, but inaccessible while we're off it.

We have an internal package that forces standards and configuration and contains a function that builds an internal profile at the project, user, or system level (So we can quickly configure their system to select packages from CRAN and the local along with a number of other settings)

the .Rprofile that's generated contains (among other things) the following:

```
repos <- getOption('repos')
repos["cloud"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
repos['internal'] <- 'http://path/to/repo/'
options(repos = repos)
```

This works great when we're in the network, but outside of the network, `install.packages` still checks that internal repo (regardless of the order of the repos).

This leads to very long waits for timeouts.

I'm trying to find a way to either:

1. **Include the repo conditionally**
2. **Reduce the timeout of install.packages**

`options(timeout = 10)` appears to have no effect.

If it will quickly determine that the repo is unavailable, I think there won't be  too much of a drop in user experience, but as it stands right now, it will take 2-3 mins to finally reject that repo.

EDIT: All other things being equal, setting the above options should reproduce the timeout issue, unless `http://path/to/repo` exists.

But in case this is a platform issue with `options(timeout = X)`, this is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```